# TapGestureRecognizer Not Working in IOS6 Maps

Tags: xcode, ios6, maps, uitapgesturerecognizer

So anyway, as normal, my app is working pretty awesome in iOS5.

Then came iOS6 with new Maps app, and it no longer function as it supposed to. (insert Roll Eyes icon here)

I have a MapView with the following user interactions:

1. User can zoom in/out by pinching.
2. User can double tap to drop a pin.

This is no longer the case with iOS6, No.2 does not work anymore.
It seems the new MapView no longer detects double tapping directly.
If I disable zooming (in IB) then it works.

So, how can I make this work?
Or perhaps it is better to change the operation from "double tap" to "long tap"?

Any suggestions or how to make it work while enabling zoom
is appreciated.

Thanks yall.

Comment: Ok, I changed the gesture to Longpress... still not working. Seems like all gestures are disabled when zooming is enabled. HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the heck.

Nobody answers this, so I'm going to answer for myself.
What I did is a simple hack.

1. implement the touchesBegan delegate in the same viewcontroller.
2. in there, detect single touch, and if detected a single touch, disable the MapkitView zooming. Hence the TapGestureRecognizer implemented for the MapKitView will response.In this
   case a double tap will response as I needed it to.
3. And when a 2 touches detected (two fingers on the screen), enable back the zooming of the MapkitView.

This works pretty ok.

Hope this helps other people who is facing the same problem with iOS6 Maps app.
Surprisingly, this still works ok for Google Maps (prior iOS6).

Thanks.